# Getting error as not a valid virtual path while downloading file in C # asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net, download, virtual-path

I have written a piece of code for downloading the file from the server. So when I download it, the file gets downloaded properly. But when I Open the document, it shows me error as.

> Failed to load particular document.

Also while debugging I get error as.

> 'https:/NVMBD1BKH150V02.IN.RIL.COM/MWSiteSurveyDoc/I-KA-ANKL-ENB-0012_C2/180.jpg' is not a valid virtual path.

when I open the URL in browser, the file is opened properly.

Here is my code below

```
protected void lnkDownload_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    try
    {
        string FulfilePath = (sender as LinkButton).CommandArgument;
        string[] filePath = FulfilePath.Split('\\');               
        string path = @"" + ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["NASSServerPath_MW_Feasibility_Download"].ToString() + "/" + filePath[7] + "/" + filePath[8];
        // Response.ContentType = ContentType;                               

        Response.ContentType = ContentType;
        Response.AppendHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=" + Path.GetFileName(path));
        Response.TransmitFile(path);
        Response.End();

    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        // objCom.ErrorLog(ex.GetType().ToString(), ex.Message, "Download Files", Session["UserName"].ToString());
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

[HttpResponse.Transmit](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.web.httpresponse.transmitfile?view=netframework-4.7#System_Web_HttpResponse_TransmitFile_System_String_) takes a server physical path to a file as a parameter. Seems you are trying to pass a remote URI instead, and there is also a typo: a slash is missing in *http://* prefix.

You either need to provide a local path to the TransmitFile method or redirect the request to the URI